# Passing database data from controller to view in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, controller, view

I'm trying to pass my data from controller to my view.

--------edit_request.blade.php--------

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')


<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title"><?= $title ?></h3>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
    <!-- form start -->
    <form method="post" id="main-form" action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="???">

        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Driver's name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="???" placeholder="Driver's name" disabled>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


@stop
```

My data should comes from my database and I don't know how to construct it in my controller.

--------AdminController.php---------

```
public function edit_request($id){
$walker= DB::table('walker')->get();
$awlker= array('first_name'  => $first_name,'last_name' => $last_name);
return View::make('edit_request')->with($walker);
}
```

Comment: You are adding controller actions on your view, this is a really bad practice, the query must go on a controller.

Comment: Do have any suggestion how will I appropriately code it?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do something like this:

**In AdminController.php**

```
$select_names = Walker::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
$walker = Walker::findOrFail($id);

return View::make('edit_request')->with($walker)->with($select_names);
```

**In edit_request.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
{{ Form::label('Select Driver') }}
{{ Form::select('driver', $select_names, null, array('class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Please select ...')) }}
</div>
```

You can read more on Form Model Binding and the Laravel Collective at https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#form-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code like :

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')


<div class="box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h3 class="box-title"><?= $title ?></h3>
    </div><!-- /.box-header -->
    <!-- form start -->
    <form method="post" id="main-form" action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$walker->id}}">

        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Driver's name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" value="{{$walker->first_name}}" placeholder="Driver's name" disabled>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


@stop

public function edit_request($id){
 $walker= DB::table('walker')->where('id',$id)->first();

 return View::make('edit_request',compact('walker'));
}
```

Hope this work for you!